# How to share settings between add-ins in MAF?

Tags: c#, maf

I am using MAF for my application to make it easily extendable. I now have the following problem: When I use `Properties.Settings.Default`, and I have multiple add-ins in one assembly, different locations for the settings are used. Is there a mechanism to share settings between the add-ins? It would be enough to share them assembly-locally.

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a method to my contract for initialization. In that initialization method, I will pass all settings and logging infrastructure, so they can properly interact with my system.